# Mapping fields in stored procedure to class properties with different names with Dapper

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I have this exert from a POCO class with many fields:

```
public class Call
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int UserAssignedToId { get; set; }
    public string UserAssignedToName { get; set; }
}
```

However my stored procedure returns different names to the properties above (in this case the Id is before:

- IdCall
- IdStatus
- IdUserAssignedTo

This is the code I am using to execute the stored procedure:

```
var call = conn.Query<Call>("CallSPName", new { IdCall = callId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

How can I specify a mapping to say I would like "IdStatus" from my stored procedure map to "StatusId" in my POCO class and "IdCall" to "CallId" etc?

I don't have access to change the stored procedures as they are controlled by DBAs and older legacy systems are using them which would break if the fields got changed in the stored procedure.

Any ideas/thoughts appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, dapper doesn't have any mapping support so you'd have to create your own mapping using either Automapper or your own custom one to do it for you.. or you could change the properties to match that from your stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing which comes to my mind is to have private properties mapped to columns returned by the stored procedure and make the public properties with the names you want setting and getting those private fields:

```
// ...
private int IdStatus;
public int StatusId {
    get { return IdStatus; }
    set { IdStatus = value; }
}
// ...
```